# Output log file through Ajax in Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have followed an SO's accepted answer on how to read the log file in Django from /var/log/gateway from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908919/python-parsing-log-file-to-extract-events-in-real-time) and I managed to output the file on terminal like here.

```
2013-05-09T11:15:02.539091+08:00 localhost gateway[5205]: System starting up...
2013-05-09T12:57:44.160246+08:00 localhost gateway[5205]: System start complete.
2013-05-09T15:13:47.428553+08:00 localhost gateway[4777]: * Unable to connect to device /home/smartsensor1. Device may be offline. *
```

The next step is, I want to output the log file and display it in html, I did it with slight modification from the original code like this.

```
def Logs(request):
    with open('../../../../../var/log/gateway') as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if line:
                print line
                return HttpResponse(line)
```

So on the client side, I put Ajax like this, based on another SO's accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836838/tail-f-in-a-webbrowser).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url : "{% url WebServiceApp.logging.Logs %}",
    success: function (data) {
            $("#output").append(data);
            setTimeout("doUpdate()", 2000);
    }
});
}

setTimeout("doUpdate()", 2000);
```

With this, the output data from Ajax kept on displaying the first line of the log file. Where in this case, is like this

```
2013-05-09T11:15:02.539091+08:00 localhost gateway[5205]: System starting up...
2013-05-09T11:15:02.539091+08:00 localhost gateway[5205]: System starting up...
2013-05-09T11:15:02.539091+08:00 localhost gateway[5205]: System starting up...
```

I know this occur because everytime ajax went to the server, the server does what it needs to do and send back the output which is the first line of the log file and output through the HttpResponse and completed the cycle and it never got a chance to do another line because it is completed already. When another query is done, it does the same thing again, and again.

So the possible solution is client ask the server one time, and the server keep output the log file line by line and send it out to client. I am not sure if this is even possible, so here I am asking any expert on how to possibly achieve the result where I can output the log file line by line/

Comment: Keeping the connection open and sending additional data as it is generated is known as long polling - but I'm unsure how you'd implement this in django. As an aside, consider using absolute, not relative Urls - what happens when your app is installed in a subdirectory?

Comment: you can establish a persistant connection using websockets

Comment: Oh ok. Let me read around about log polling, maybe it will give me hints on how to solve my case here. Hmm, thanks for comment on the urls but won't it be in cause the same problem when I use absolute url instead of relative url? I mean it still won't find it?

Comment: @dm03514 thanks. I forgot to mention in my question that to apply any parallel server is not an option currently. So I have to use ajax or look into this long polling mentioned by Basic for the time being.

Comment: re: urls `/var/log/blah` will always point at the same place. `../../../var/log/blah` will change where it's pointing at, depending on where the path is being requested from. eg from `/srv/www/test` it would point at `/var/log/blah` but from `/srv/www/test/something` it would point at `/srv/var/log/blah`

Comment: Just one thing, you want that the first time the ajax is executed the view returns the whole file and next time just the first line am I right?

Comment: @Basic I see what you mean there. Ok I should fix it to the same point.

Comment: @PauloBu The first time is as what you said, but the second time it runs, the file is changed and get appended at the end by something so I would like to return the appended part of the file. So basically, the next output would start display from the line where it hasn't been displayed to the end of the file.

Comment: In my answer I describe the process for doing that but instead of the last line, I return the first line for next queries. The idea is pretty much the same. Maybe you can parse the last date of the file and then next queries include the lines older than that date, but the idea is pretty much the same. Using get parameters to control the ajax view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to solve this is by doing the Server-Sent Event

On server side, I use [django-sse](https://github.com/niwibe/django-sse) that is dependent on [sse](https://github.com/niwibe/sse)

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import View
from django_sse.views import BaseSseView
import time
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import now
from dateutil import parser

class MySseEvents(BaseSseView):
    def iterator(self):
        while True:
            if not os.path.exists('/var/log/gateway'):
                file('/var/log/gateway', 'w+').close()
            with open('/var/log/gateway') as f:
                while True:
                    #get the current time
                    currenttime = now()
                    #read a line from gateway
                    line = f.readline()
                    if line:
                        #split the line read into 4 section
                        str = line.split(' ',3)
                        #compare if the time from the log file is less than the current time
                        logtime = parser.parse(str[0])
                        if logtime >= currenttime:
                            #print when the log is written after the current time
                            output = '%s: %s' % (datetime.strftime(logtime,'%d/%m %H:%M %p'), str[3])
                            self.sse.add_message("line", output)
                            time.sleep(1)
                            yield
```

The `if logtime >= currenttime:` check that I did above is to make sure that html only print out the logs after the time the page is loaded not the whole log file.

Then on the HTML5 side I did similar to what the example made by the author shown on the first link that I have provided.

```
<div id="tab9" class="tab_content">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p> Shows the records of the logs on gateway.</p>
                <div style="border:1px solid; height: 200px; width: 850px; overflow: auto;" id="output"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var source = new EventSource('/gtwy/logging/');
    var events_dom = $("#output");

    source.addEventListener("line", function(e) {
        events_dom.append(e.data + "<br>");
    });
});
</script>
```

Using this, I managed to display the log as it is available. The only problem that I face is to create the gateway file itself that it needs permission because I'm trying to create it in `/var/log`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use an idea like this:

Using `GET` parameters you can control the view's method like this:

```
def Logs(request):
    whole_file = True
    if request.GET.get('whole_file') == 0:
        whole_file = False
    return_string = ''
    with open('../../../../../var/log/gateway') as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if line:
                return_string += line + '<br>' # <br> is for breakline html, do it your way
                if not whole_file: break # break if you only need first line
    return HttpResponse(line)
```

This way, you include a variable inside the get parameter that tells your view whether to return the whole log file (first time) or just the first line (next times).

Then in your ajax you will have to include a way to insert `GET` parameters to the url. You use the `{{url}}` tag an I'm not quite sure how to do it with it but I'm sure you'll find something in the doc, if you can't then try some other approach like an static string (not very pretty) or create your own custom tag for it.

This would be an example of your possible javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url : "/ajax_log/?whole_file=0", //this will request the whole file
    success: function (data) {
            $("#output").append(data);
            setTimeout("doUpdate()", 2000);
    }
});
}

setTimeout("doNextUpdate()", 2000);

function doNextUpdate(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url : "/ajax_log/?whole_file=1", //this will request the just the first line            success: function (data) {
                $("#output").append(data);
                setTimeout("doUpdate()", 2000);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

That is my idea to accomplish what you want. I hope it helps.