# Parsing log files after 30 seconds in real time

Tags: python, apache, real-time, logfile

I m writing a simple python script to analyze the logs in real time. I don't know how to move the cursor to the end of the freshly written data in log files in 30 seconds.

I have read all the related links [Python parsing log file to extract events in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908919/python-parsing-log-file-to-extract-events-in-real-time/11909244#11909244)
and this http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/follow.py
I have also read about seek() function but I'm not getting how do I use it.

But none of them answer to my questions.
I don't even know to do I start.

```
import time
import csv
import parser as p
def follow(thefile):
    logfile = open("access.log","r")
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    loglines = thefile.read()
    p.process1(loglines)  # user defined function 1
    p.process2(loglines)  # user defined function 2
    print "Lines Converted: "
    for line in loglines:
        print line,

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(True):
        follow()
        time.sleep(30)
```

After reading the updated data in log files written in 30 seconds, the function should call the user defined function to perform the other operation on the new log data.

Comment: Look here http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577968-log-watcher-tail-f-log/

Comment: don't re-open the file every time you call follow.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, @balderman can you just show this with an example?

Comment: @AShelly, how do you propose to do this?